# Implement a custom ASP.NET ListControl that post back data with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, custom-controls

I'm writing a custom server control inherited from ListControl.
I'm able to change the rendering of the control (overriding the Render method), using a "li" with a custom CSS instead of using the normal tag "option", but how can i send the selected data back to the control?
I've implemented the selection using javascript.
I suppose that i've to use javascript to send to the control the selected value, but i don't know how.
If anyone could bring me in the right way, i'll appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use some jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({  
         type: "GET",  
         url: "process_me.aspx?value=" + $("#id-of-hidden-value-of-list").val(),  
         success: function(){  
            //success (not finished)
            alert("woot!")
            }  
         });
```

i mean that's quick and dirty. And use Request.QueryString collection to pick up the value in the code-behind.

You could instead implement a hidden control in the render method. ASP.NET fan boi's would have you implementing [IPostBackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx).

You could keep it simpler, rendering a plain html hidden and use the Request.Form collection on postback.

```
Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='list-value'>");
..

document.forms[0].list-value.value = selectedValue;
document.forms[0].submit();

.. 

if(Request.Form["list-value"]) != "" { // do something }
```

And an alt to ajax is some jquery / javascript that either writes the selected valu to a hidden or the form's querystring before submitting it (which is what that ajax code is doing).

Comment: Hi BobTodd. 
I can't use that solution, because i want to write a custom server control and the "ajax" jquery method could only be used into the page and not from the custom control.

Comment: you can emit jquery from the custom control using Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock() in your Render() method. Just ensure your hidden controls have unique ids in case u need multiple custom controls on one page